# Using 'Number' class instead of primitives on a game?

Tags: java, performance, numbers, lwjgl, primitive

Right now, I'm developing a heavy 2D game write in `java+LWJGL` (ok, it could have looked funny when I said "heavy 2D game", but trust me, I'll be using LOTS of resources), and, well, let's say I have TOC (TOC is in Brazil, maybe in english it's... `OCD`?), so *I have to write, for everything I'll use third-party, an API*. Like, I have an API for LWJGL (an API for an API of OpenGL, lol), and a lot of other API classes. And, inside these APIs, *on constructors, I never use primitives* (constructors only, fields I still use primitives), but *instead I use Number class* (so I can call the methods using Integer, Float, Double, and whatever I want). Then, inside the constructor, I *translate the number*, using `number.doubleValue()` or `number.intValue()`, depending on what I want.

So, do this can *affect dramatically* the *performance* of my game? Until now, in the *early-middle* development stage, my performance is still OK but I'm worried of it causing me to re-write most part of the code late. Oh, and sorry for my soo bad english, it's not my primary language.

Comment: Beside the fact that you can google for the difference between primitives and their Object representation - I have doubt that nowadays computers would notice any difference between them in terms of performance. You are talking about a difference in the size of "bit"... Finally it depends on what you need: Just a value of 2.0? use `double`. `2.0` with converting / comparission functions and all the fancy stuff OOP is providing? use `Double`

Comment: Yes, I already did a research about their difference, but I was worried if creating a new object everytime for a primitive would be performance-impacting (as I've seen on Integer.class, there is a cache system for getting the Integer object of an int, but I assume there is no thing like this for Double and Float, since these are really large numbers?).

Comment: The biggest difference is that you can `null` Objects, but not primitives. So, when you have the requirement to have some values in a "uninitialized state" - The Object is better, cause otherwhise you have to work with things like "-1" on int - which will not work, when it also can be a negative number. Like: "How many people said yes?": `0` or did nobody vote? --> `0` or `null`.

Comment: I couldn't stay half of the question gray. If I understand your reasons well, using `double` should do as it can represent any primitive value except `long` exactly (when storing a `long` in `double` you lose 8 bits, this can be acceptable or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use boxed primitives unless you really need them. A good reasons may be

- you need an representation for the undefined state (use `null`)
- you put them into `Object`-accepting classes (List, Set, Map, ...) and want to avoid boxing (by working with boxed values all the time)

Anything performance-related must be benchmarked first, otherwise you can find yourself optimizing a piece of program taking no measurable time or even "pessimizing" it. Low-level optimizations in Java are pretty hard, so you'd better concentrate on clarity and readability, so you can *measure* the speed, identify the bottlenecks, and optimize them afterwards.

Concerning boxed primitives, IMHO the biggest performance impact doesn't come from object creation but from the indirection (creation happens once, repeated cache misses are costly).

I disagree with dognose concerning the "fancy OOP stuff". Everything the classes offer can be used without boxing and working with boxed primitives is a pain the OOP methods can't ever make good (the unexpected `NullPointerException`s, non-working conversions, etc. are IMHO too bad).